# I am trying to Automate security testing of web applications using owasp ZAP in jenkins.I am getting the following issue

Tags: jenkins, zap

The issue is as follows:

```
5825 [ZAP-SpiderInitThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.spider.Spider  - Spider initializing...
 5854 [ZAP-SpiderInitThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.spider.Spider  - Starting spider...
 5854 [ZAP-SpiderInitThread-0] WARN org.zaproxy.zap.spider.Spider  - No seeds available for the Spider. Cancelling scan...
 5854 [ZAP-SpiderInitThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.spider.SpiderThread  - Spider scanning complete: false
    [ZAP Jenkins Plugin] SPIDER SCAN STATUS [ 100% ]
    [ZAP Jenkins Plugin] ALERTS COUNT [ 0 ]
```

Can anyone resolve this issue?

Comment: can u please share the jenkins version and zap version ?

Comment: jenkins version:2.89.4,ZAP Version :2.7.0

Comment: Have you checked the URL is correct? Can you access the URL from the jenkins box?

Comment: Lots of great answers! Thanks for your help!This is resolved :)

Comment: @Reshmak I am noticing the same error. Can you share how this issue was resolved?

Comment: @Puru The url that I have given was incorrect.